# Chrome htaccess cache not enabled

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, htaccess

When I go to an internal website using Chrome, I have to enter htaccess login credentials. However, in Firefox, when the htaccess login popup appears, the credentials are already filled in (obfuscated by dots). But I don't have to type anything, just click "OK".

Is there are setting in Chrome that would provide this same behavior wherein I can just click a button rather than typing in the credentials?

Password saving is enabled in Chrome.